# Send a notification with R under Windows

Tags: r, postgresql, datatable

I am currently recording / updating my tables in the bank with the R language:

`dbWriteTable (with," table ", table, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)`

This script of mine that updates the tables in R in a postgres database, is automatically run from time to time by a windows task.
I need to know when the information is recorded or not, perhaps in an alert format on the screen, or something that catches the eye.

note: I know that there is "r.out", but it overwrites, does not warn when the problem occurs, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call Windows Powershell:

1. Run powershell and [authorize script execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

2. Create a [notification script](https://gist.github.com/loge5/7ec41e2e2f0e0293fdcc5155499e9072) and execute it with `system`:

```
showMessage <- function(message) {
  MessageScript <-'
    [CmdletBinding()]
    
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    
    $notificationTitle = "{message}"
    
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
    $template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText01)
    
    #Convert to .NET type for XML manipuration
    $toastXml = [xml] $template.GetXml()
    $toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text").AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null
    
    #Convert back to WinRT type
    $xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)
    
    $toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
    $toast.Tag = "PowerShell"
    $toast.Group = "PowerShell"
    $toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddMinutes(5)
    #$toast.SuppressPopup = $true
    
    $notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("PowerShell")
    $notifier.Show($toast);'

  system('powershell',input=glue::glue(MessageScript),show.output.on.console=F)
  
}

showMessage(message = 'this is a test')
```

This works for me:
[image]

Comment: i will try, ty!!

Comment: See my edit : created a function so that message can easily be modified